# How to extract internal links with numbers in scrapy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy, I am trying to extract internal links which have 3-4 digit number in them.

Here's an example of one of the internal links.

https://www.example.com/detail-info/150-exampleurl

Here's my code.

```
for links in response.css('section.content-current'):
        internal_link = links.xpath('(*//a/@href)').re(r"\d+")
```

I am able to get all the internal links on the page using this code, without `.re`. Please help me write the `regex` to extract only the URL which has 2 or 3 consecutive numbers in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the whole string that contains at least three digits:

```py
.re(r"(?s).*\d{3}.*")
```

*Details*

- `(?s)`  - a `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` inline modifier that makes `.` match across lines
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\d{3}` - any three digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.